# The difference between a physical force and a component force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors

I'm troubled about the distinction between what I am tentatively calling physical forces and component forces. Consider an object of mass $m$ on an inclined plane that is at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal. The physical force of gravity creates a downward force $f_p = mg$ on the object, but at the same time, there is a force along the incline plane of $f_c = mg\sin \theta$.

Each of these forces is called a "force", but they are different kinds of things. Yes, they both account for an acceleration of a mass, but $f_p$ has components. You can ask, for example, what is the component of $f_p$ parallel to the incline plane (answer: $f_c$). You can't ask that about $f_c$, can you? What I mean is that $f_c$ doesn't have components. You can't ask what is the component of $f_c$ vertically towards the ground; the question makes no sense. Since $f_p$ has this dramatically important feature that $f_c$ lacks, it seems that they are different kinds of things, so why are they both called forces?

My real problem isn't in understanding this situation---I think I understand it just fine---my problem is in terminology. It seems confusing. How would you explain this to a student? How would you characterize forces that have components and forces that don't?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The last two sentences are questions. What is it about them that you find unlcear?

Answer (score 0):

> You can ask, for example, what is the component of  parallel to the incline plane (answer: ). You can't ask that about , can you?

Of course you can, you can ask for the components of $f_c$ along the x and y directions, for example (which would be $f_{cx} = f_c \cos(\theta)$.

What you call physical and component forces are only distinguishable by whether or not they describe an entire interaction between two bodies. For all other purposes their behavior is the same.

Comment: If that were true, then $f_c$ would have a non-zero component that is horizontal, meaning that it would be able to accelerate an object in the horizontal, but since $f_c$ is due to the vertical force of gravity, that can't be true.

Comment: No, a force or component of a force does not need to have a non-zero horizontal components to have components.

Comment: You forget that the acceleration is determined by the net force on the object.  The fact that there is a component along the x axis does not tell you if the object will or not accelerate along this axis.

Comment: I can't figure out how your comment responds to mine. I didn't say that a force has to have a non-zero horizontal component to have components.

Comment: @nasu, I suppose you could say that the horizontal component of $f_c$ is cancelled out by the horizontal component of component of $f_n=f_p \cos\theta$ on the other side. However, there is no sense in which $f_c$ has a tendency to accelerate anything in the horizontal direction--it is a pure formal fiction. By contrast, $f_p$ does have a tendency to accelerate things in the direction of $f_c$. But this is something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have come up with an answer. The problem is in considering that the component force is in some sense a part of the principle force, or occurring at the same time. The problem goes away if you see the force components as an alternate way of viewing the problem. It isn't a part of the original force, and it doesn't occur with the original force. Rather, when analyzing the forces on an object, there are different ways to view the very same force. You have to pick one of those ways of viewing the force to analyze the acceleration of the object.